# Images are shown out of the border of the pdf. Apache FOP

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am trying to create a pdf document that contains some images. My problem is that the images are hown out of the border of the document. I am using Apache FOP 1.1.

Here it is the xsl-fo document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" line-stacking-strategy="font-height">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master margin-bottom="36pt" margin-left="72pt" margin-right="72pt" margin-top="36pt" master-name="pm0" page-height="792pt" page-width="612pt">
            <fo:region-body margin-bottom="36pt" margin-top="36pt" overflow="visible" region-name="body"/>
            <fo:region-before extent="720pt" overflow="visible" region-name="header"/>
            <fo:region-after display-align="after" extent="720pt" overflow="visible" region-name="footer"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pm0" orphans="2" white-space-collapse="false" widows="2">
        <fo:flow flow-name="body">
            <fo:block end-indent="0pt" line-height="13.55pt" space-after="8pt" start-indent="0pt" text-align="start" text-indent="0pt">
                <fo:inline font-family="Calibri, sans-serif" font-size="11pt">TEST1</fo:inline>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block end-indent="0pt" line-height="13.55pt" space-after="8pt" start-indent="0pt" text-align="start" text-indent="0pt">
                <fo:external-graphic content-height="214.55pt" content-width="310.55pt" height="214.55pt" scaling="non-uniform" src="url('file:///C:/Development_Test/test1.png')" width="310.55pt"/>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block end-indent="0pt" line-height="13.55pt" space-after="8pt" start-indent="0pt" text-align="start" text-indent="0pt">
                <fo:inline font-family="Calibri, sans-serif" font-size="11pt">TEST2</fo:inline>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block end-indent="0pt" line-height="13.55pt" space-after="8pt" start-indent="0pt" text-align="start" text-indent="0pt">
                <fo:external-graphic content-height="356.35pt" content-width="139.9pt" height="356.35pt" scaling="non-uniform" src="url('file:///C:/Development_Test/test2.png')" width="139.9pt"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

The created pdf looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem comes from having the attribute `line-stacking-strategy="font-height"` set in the `fo:root`, so that its value is inherited by all the blocks in the FO document.

As per the [XSL recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#line-stacking-strategy), the value `font-height` makes the processor build lines using the *nominal-requested-line-rectangle*, meaning that only the properties of the `fo:block` will be taken into account when computing the line height, **ignoring the inline elements such as `fo:external-graphic`**.

In other words, as all your `fo:block` elements have `line-height="13.55pt"` the FO processor creates lines whose height is exactly 13.55pt, regardless of what is inside the blocks. The images, which are taller, are then placed in these lines according to [`vertical-align`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#vertical-align) (which defaults to `baseline`), overflowing over the preceding lines and the page margins.

**Solution:** use `line-stacking-strategy="max-height"` instead; you may want to set `vertical-align` on the images too.

A final note of warning: you are using a *5-year-old* version of FOP; at the moment the latest version is 2.2, released in April 2017.

Comment: Or don;t set line-stacking-strategy and let the processor do it's job

Comment: Hello, I've solved my issue by putting line-stacking-strategy="max-height" in the fo:block.

Comment: Unfortunately at the moment I'm forced to you use FOP 1.0. Hopefully in the future will upgrade to latest version.